# socket.io loses connection frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I am using the socket.io framework for a chat module in Objective-C code base. The connection however loses very frequently, sometimes right after the connection is made, it's disconnected. I have looked for background app and incoming call scenarios as answered in SO, but here it happens even if app is active and chat is in process.

Here is how I make the connection:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://domainAddress:port"];
self.socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL: url config: @{@"connectParams": @{@"user_id": [NSNumber numberWithInt:user_id]}}];
[self.socket setReconnects:YES];
```

I used the `setReconnects:` method as initially the socket was not reconnecting itself.

Please let me know how to resolve the issue and how can I debug more further.

Comment: I would suggest also attaching the logs in the question. Pass log(Bool) in the config object and add the logs to your question, this will help you with debugging. Also try an see if passing forceNew(Bool) in the config object fixes the issue.